# Google Sheet, can the pivot column header not disappear if there is no value in it?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I've created a pivot table grouped by date:

- B = Date
- C = Deal
- D = Follow Up
- E = No Deal

The original formula I use:

```
=Query(
    Importrange("URL_Sheet"; "LEAD!B3960:X");
     "Select Col1,
     Count(Col16) where
     Col1 >= date '"&TEXT(OVERVIEW!C5;"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and
     Col1 <= date '"&TEXT(OVERVIEW!C6;"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and
     Col16 contains '"&OVERVIEW!C4&"'
     group by Col1 pivot Col20 label Col1 'DATE'"
    ;0)
```

The problem started appearing when I filtered the date range (Col1) to around 7 days or less. Which makes the Deal column disappear and the data shifts to the left.

I need every column to stay in place so that the sum and avg formulas calculate the correct data, especially the pivot header section so it doesn't move when the data is missing/empty.

Is it possible to make the pivot header not disappear in this case?

I've created a demonstration sheet that shows "The Deal Column" will disappear if the end date is changed from 4 to 3 or lower.

[Demo Query Pivot](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OSetSj7B5pBEAgcEpzWFMEPPlmwneLCT0CZ7n5suCgo/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is possible, even if you use the in-built pivot table functionality if there's no data for a given label then the pivot table won't include it. You need to use a different solution if you want the columns to persist.

Answer (score 0):

Many thank to Prashanth KV from Google Docs Community who provide the answer.

Here is the formula that work in my demo sheet.

```
=query(Query({'Data Source'!A2:C;Overview!E3+1\Overview!A3\"Deal"};"Select Col1,Count(Col2) where Col1 >= date '"&TEXT(Overview!C3;"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col1 <= date '"&TEXT(Overview!E3+1;"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col2 contains '"&Overview!A3&"' group by Col1 pivot Col3 label Col1 'DATE'" ;0);"Select * where Col1 <= date '"&TEXT(Overview!E3;"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

Comment: Prashanth is very good. However, it seems to me that this formula only *happens* to work for you. It assumes that the missing value will only ever be "Deal" (which is likely not true); and it works by adding only "Deal" to the day following the end date you choose for the search (which won't always fix the problem). For instance, choose a a start and end date of 6/2 and 6/3, then set all of the 'Data Source' Col C values to "Deal" for all of the dates from 6/2 to 6/4. You will see that the result only shows "Deal," not "Deal" and "Follow Up" and "No Deal."